# A property of minimal homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space . Given $\delta>0$ and a subset $A\subseteq X$ we define 
\begin{equation}
A^\delta=\{x\in X: d(x, a)<\delta \text{ for some } a\in A\}
\end{equation}

Define the Hausdroff metric between $A, B\subseteq X$ by

\begin{equation}
d_H(A, B)=\inf \{ \delta: A\subseteq B^\delta, B\subseteq A^\delta\}
\end{equation} 
$f:X\to X$ is a minimal homeomorphis, if  every point of $X$ has a dense orbit.

In a paper author claim that if $f:X\to X$ is a minimal homeomorphis,  then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for every homeomorphim $g:X\to X$ with $d(f(x), g(x))<\delta$, for all $x\in X$, we have $d_H(X, \overline{O_g(z)})<\epsilon$ for all $z\in X$, where $O_g(z)=\{g^n(z)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: This looks like a definition chase; not much to prove here unless I'm mistaken. $f$ is eventually close to anything, and $g$ is close to $f$, so $g$ is eventually close to anything. Formalize that as an epsilon-delta proof if you desire.

Comment: I might be missing something since I haven't written out the details, but I imagine compactness is there either for other applications or just to ensure the Hausdorff Distance is finite

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, Thanks a lot. I need details in my research. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in X$, and $n\in\Bbb N$, let 
$$O_n(x)=\{\,f^k(x)\mid 1\le k\le n\,\} $$
and
$$U_n(x)=\{\,y\in X\mid d(y,O_n)<\tfrac12\epsilon\,\}. $$
By minimality of $f$, we have $\bigcup_n U_n(x)=X$ and then by compactness $X=U_n(x)$ for some $n=n(x)$. 
Then $d_H(X,O_{n(x)}(x))<\frac12\epsilon$, and as $d_H(X,O_{n(x)}(x'))$ is continuous in $x'$, we see that  $n(x')\le n(x)$ for all $x'$ in an open neighbourhood $V_x$ of $x$.
The $V_x$ cover $X$, so by compactness there is a finite subcover. If $N$ is the maximum over the finitely many $n(x)$  involved in this subcover then we find that 
$$d_H(X,O_N(x))<\frac12\epsilon $$
for all $x\in X$.

Let $\delta_0=\frac12\epsilon$.
By continuity of $f$ and compactness once again, there recursively exists $\delta_{n+1}>0$ such that $d(x,x')<\delta_{n+1}$ implies $d(f(x),f(x'))<\frac12\delta_n$.
Let $\delta=\frac12\min\{\delta_0,\ldots,\delta_N\}$.
Now if $d(f,g)<\delta)$, then for any $z$, we can show
by induction that $d(f^k(z),g^k(z))<\delta_{N-k}$ for $k=1,\ldots, N$. In particular, $d(f^N(z),g^N(z))<\frac12\epsilon$ and the claim follows.